# Problems on Mac with java.util.zip.* (Extraction)

Tags: java, macos, zip, extract

I made a program and I created an export function for documents (entries).
The procedure: The user has favorited documents. There exist 2-3 strategies
(BibTex,RIS,HTML) a user can choose to export his documents.
For each strategy a new .zip file is being generated with all documents inside.
The created .zip archives are sent to the user via email.

For me ( Windows ) it works great. I can extract those archives without any problems.
But a friend of my, who is using Mac, gets errors while extracting them and I do not know why.

Here the important code:

```
for ( String strategy : strategies ) {
// Coderedundanz
// Jede Strategie benötigt eigene Parameter
if (strategy.equals("BibTex")) {
    _zipName = "ezdl_export_bibtex";
    _fileExtension = ".bib";
    _strategy = csf.bibTex;
}
else if (strategy.equals("RIS")) {
    _zipName = "ezdl_export_ris";
    _fileExtension = ".ris";
    _strategy = csf.ris;
}
else if (strategy.equals("HTML")) {
    _zipName = "ezdl_export_html";
    _fileExtension = ".html";
    _strategy = csf.html;
}
else {
    _zipName = _zipExtension = "";
    _fileExtension = "";
    _strategy = null;
}

// Gibt es eine korrekte Strategie?
if ( !_zipName.equals("") && !_fileExtension.equals("") && _strategy != null) {
    // 1. .zip Datei generieren
    // 2. Für jedes TextDocument eine eigene Datei erstellen
    // 3. Datei in die .zip Datei einfügen
    // 4. .zip Datei schließen und in die E-Mail hinzufügen
    File file = File.createTempFile(_zipName + _zipExtension, ".tmp");
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    out.setLevel(6);
    for ( TextDocument document : documents ) {
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry( document.getOid() + _fileExtension));

        String temp = _strategy.print ( (TextDocument) document).asString().toString();

        out.write( temp.getBytes() );
        out.closeEntry();
    }

    out.finish();
    out.close();

    PreencodedMimeBodyPart part_x = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart("base64");
    part_x.setFileName(_zipName + _zipExtension);
    part_x.setContent(new String(Base64Coder.encode( getBytesFromFile (file))), "text/plain");
    multi.addBodyPart(part_x);

    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
```

You see for each strategy an own archive is being created.
The program loops through the documents (TextDocument)
and with _strategy.print you get a String as output.

As I said.. for me it works great, but not on Mac.
Are there any differences? I guess.. .zip is .zip.
Or should I create tarballs (.tar.gz) for Mac?

**EDIT:**

```
serena:tmp3 alex$ unzip ezdl_export_bibtex.zip 
Archive:  ezdl_export_bibtex.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  ezdl_export_bibtex.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ezdl_export_bibtex.zip or
        ezdl_export_bibtex.zip.zip, and cannot find
```

Here is a screen: http://img3.imageshack.us/i/ziperror.png. It shows the error: "Unable to unarchive - Error - 1 - Operation not permitted"

I also changed my code to:

```
out.write( temp.getBytes() );
out.flush();
out.closeEntry();
```

But still the same problem.

Comment: What are the errors you speak of? (Please add them to your question with stack traces if possible.)

Comment: ..and if the 'flush()' does not work, try posting an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html), preferably with comments in English.  ;)

Comment: Oh.. right. I didnt see my german comments :-) These are just notes for me.. but.. i guess these notes are really outdated

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: It seems like you have two potential points of failure: the zip part and the MIME part.  Is it possible to isolate these from one another?

Comment: Right. I changed the MIME type from text/plain to application/zip. But I guess it has no effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it doesn't address your problem directly, you can verify the integrity of the `zip` file using the [`-t`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/unzip/) option on the command line.

```
$ unzip -t java-puzzlers.zip | tail -1
No errors detected in compressed data of java-puzzlers.zip.
```

In addition, you can examine the parent directory's permissions, walking up the path until you see a problem.

```
$ ls -ld ..
drwxr-xr-x@ 26 trashgod  staff  884 Jan 17  2010 ..
$ ls -ld ../..
drwx------+ 23 trashgod  staff  782 Dec 17 17:15 ../..
```

Addendum: If it "has something to do with encoding," I always start with Joel Spolsky's oft-cited [article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on the subject. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654245) may be helpful, too.

Comment: Hey trashgod. After several tests I got my problem, but no solution.
It has something to do with file encoding.
I tried encoding my string (content of the files in zip) in UTF-8
(URLEncoder.encode(string,"UTF-8")). And voilà! MAC
has no problems to open the .zip archive.. so no errors occur.
It works, but my files are useless because everything is encoded
in UTF-8. So i need an encode type which is accepted from
all systems. I tried "ISO-8859-1" but I got the same error on MAC..how can
i handle my problem now?

Comment: If `unzip -t` reports no errors, I'm guessing your strategy uses the [Windows encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) by default. What does `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` produce? How is UTF-8 useless?

Comment: Im running tomcat 7 on a linux server.
System.getProperty("file.encoding") returns "ANSI_X3.4-1968"
UTF-8 is useless because when i open the files i just the things
like "2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fsummary%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.12.1933%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%3C%2Ful%3E%3Cbr..."
It is not really readable... So i need an encoding type for all
platforms.. for linux it works either.

Comment: Well, that looks like URL encoding using UTF-8; but since all values are < 128, it's isomorphic to ASCII (ANSI_X3.4-1968), which is your strategy's default encoding. I've elaborated above.

Comment: It didnt work either. String.getBytes("UTF-8"); did the trick for me. I think my problem was that I generated Strings "on the fly" and addded them directly to the .zip file. Now I tried to create temporary files which I add later to the .zip file. This worked for me. Thanks guys!

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Please consider clicking the gray check mark on the left to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `flush()` on the output stream prior to the `closeEntry()` call.

Comment: I informed me about the error. Some people say it has something to do with passwords. But I didnt set any password. Other people say it has something to do with file rights. The file must be read-&writeable. But if java offers these classes.. why there should be such problems? I inserted a new flush() before I close the whole stream..but still the same error.. I dont get it:/ Any other ideas?

Comment: "Any other ideas?"  Yes, I already offered another idea.  Post an SSCCE.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I didnt see your post. Now I got my problem (as I posted below) but unfortunately no solution.